# symbol precision mismatch

Tags: cleos

```
cleos --url http://127.0.0.1:8888 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:8899 push action eosio.token create '["eosio", "2000000000.0000 KBS"]' --permission eosio.token@active

cleos --url http://127.0.0.1:8888 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:8899 push action eosio.token issue '["eosio", "100000000.0000 KBS", ""]' --permission eosio@active

cleos --url http://127.0.0.1:8888 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:8899 system newaccount eosio intblue11112 EOS6w5oLk1NcLvvnfW4YVqeohoX3GV3t79LT8CJEZczBTEJVKYzeC EOS6w5oLk1NcLvvnfW4YVqeohoX3GV3t79LT8CJEZczBTEJVKYzeC --stake-net "10000.0000 KBS" --stake-cpu "10000.0000 KBS" --buy-ram-kbytes 8192

assertion failure with message: symbol precision mismatch
```

why ?

Comment: cleos --url http://127.0.0.1:8888 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:8899 push action eosio.token issue '["eosio", "100000000.0000 KBS", ""]' --permission eosio@active what is the third argument here ?

Answer (score 1):

When you build from source, you can specify what the core symbol token will be by adding the flag `-s`:

`./eosio_build.sh -s "KBS"`

```
printf "Usage: %s \\n[Build Option -o <Debug|Release|RelWithDebInfo|MinSizeRel>] \\n[CodeCoverage -c] \\n[Doxygen -d] \\n[CoreSymbolName -s <1-7 characters>] \\n[Avoid Compiling -a]\\n[Noninteractive -y]\\n\\n" "$0" 1>&2
# ... \\n[CoreSymbolName -s <1-7 characters>]
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/scripts/eosio_build.sh#L104

```
# CORE_SYMBOL_NAME="SYS"
CORE_SYMBOL_NAME="KBS"
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/scripts/eosio_build.sh#L38

Answer (score 0):

It only accept system token for **newaccount action** . It could be "SYS" or  "EOS" ...

You can check it at eos/contracts/eosiolib/core_symbol.hpp.

And change token name to **KBS**